# Unable to install TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, windows-10

I am unable to install TypeScript in Windows 10 with node version 6.3.0 and npm version 3.10.3. Getting below error

```
33 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
34 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "typescript"
35 error node v6.3.0
36 error npm  v3.10.3
37 error code ECONNREFUSED
38 error errno ECONNREFUSED
39 error syscall connect
40 error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 151.101.8.162:443
40 error     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1008:11)
40 error     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1031:20)
40 error     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
40 error  { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 151.101.8.162:443
40 error     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1008:11)
40 error     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1031:20)
40 error     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
40 error   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
40 error   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
40 error   syscall: 'connect',
40 error   address: '151.101.8.162',
40 error   port: 443 }
41 error If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
41 error 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
42 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` means the connection is refused; and the suggestion is to configure the proxy server *"If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'"*

Comment: How can i find my proxy?

Comment: This is not a programming question, you should move your question to superuser.

Comment: Try running "npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/"

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was setting the registry like mentioned by Abhishek in the comments, but with the `https://` so:

`npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

For further help and other solutions check [issue 8293 on npm Github repository](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8293)